# Cannot invoke npm in PowerShell, even though it is in the system's path

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, npm, path-variables

This is my path:

```
PS> $Env:Path
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;D:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;D:\cmder;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\caiodomingos\.nvm\versions\node\v10.16.3\bin;C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\caiodomingos\.nvm\versions\node\v10.16.3\lib;D:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%NVM_HOME%;%NVM_SYMLINK%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;C:\gradle;C:\android-sdk\tools\bin;;C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Roaming\np
```

Note the following NodJS-related entries, in sequence:

```
C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\caiodomingos\.nvm\versions\node\v10.16.3\bin
C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\caiodomingos\.nvm\versions\node\v10.16.3\lib
D:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

But when I type `npm -v`,
Powershell throws this error:

```
Program 'npm' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file 
for this operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm
+ ~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: As basic question is npm installed in any of the mentioned paths? From my short search default folder should be C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm, but you only have D:\Program Files\nodejs in your path variable.

Comment: @OlafReitz: No, `C:\Program Files\nodejs` (or equivalent) is the correct PATH entry; `npm.cmd` is located in that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- *Either*: Remove the following entries from your `$env:PATH` variable.

```
C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\caiodomingos\.nvm\versions\node\v10.16.3\bin
C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\caiodomingos\.nvm\versions\node\v10.16.3\lib
```

- *Or*: Invoke `npm` as `npm.cmd` and `node` as `node.exe`

---

Your symptom implies the following:

- There is a directory in your `$env:PATH`variable that contains a file named *just* `npm` - *without a filename extension*...
- *and* that directory doesn't *also* contain files with the same but an *executable filename extension*, such as `.cmd` or `.exe`...
- *and* that directory is listed *first* in `$env:PATH`, before any other directories that `npm` files *with* executable extensions, such as `npm.cmd`, ...

In a normal NodeJS installation on Windows (installed in `$env:ProgramFiles\NodeJs` by default), the installation folder contains a `npm.cmd` batch file for invoking npm, alongside a Unix shell script in the same folder named just `npm` - *without a filename extension*.

`npm.cmd` takes precedence over the extension-less `npm`, so invoking just `npm` works as expected.

`C:\Users\caio1\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\caiodomingos\.nvm\versions\node\v10.16.3\bin` is a directory containing a *Linux* installation of NodeJs.

In a Linux installation, there is obviously no need for a *batch file*, so only an extension-less `npm` Unix shell script is present.

Since this directory comes *before* your regular NodeJS installation directory (`D:\Program Files\nodejs`) in your `$env:PATH` value, PowerShell attempts to invoke the extension-less Unix shell script when you submit `npm`, which - predictably - fails.

Specifically, because the `npm` file has no *executable* file name extension, PowerShell invokes it as a *document* rather than as an executable, and fails to do so because no application is registered with the Windows (graphical) shell (File Explorer) for opening documents that have no filename extension.